# Starting python bottle in a thread/Process and another daemon next to it

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing, bottle

Ok, so this may be a little bit unorthodox or I'm just stupid or both :)

I'm trying a very simple setup where I start a bottle server in one `Process` instance and start a smallish TFTP server in another instance.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import bottle
import sys
import tftpy
from multiprocessing import Process

def main():
    try:
        t = Process(target=bottle.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8080))
        t.daemon = True
        t.start()
        t.join()
        h = Process(target=tftpy.TftpServer('/srv/tftp').listen('0.0.0.0', 69))
        h.start()
        h.join()

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        sys.stdout.write("Aborted by user.\n")
        sys.exit(1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Unless I'm totally crazy, I'd expect them to start up in parallel. In reality, what happens is that bottle starts and locks whole thing up. If I exit bottle, TFTP daemon starts.

I also tried a similar approach with `threading` module, with about same results.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are several issues:

- you call `run()` in the main thread. You should pass arguments in `args` instead:

  ```
  Process(target=bottle.run, kwargs=dict(host='0.0.0.0', port=8080))
  ```
- you call t.join() which blocks until t process ends before h.start(). Join after all processes are started instead
- bottle, tftpy might not be compatible with multiprocessing module. You could try subprocess module if so

Comment: Calling `run` on the main thread was the issue. Thanks man, you opened my eyes to something very obvious which I was just overlooking! :)

Comment: As a side note: Both bottle and tftp are IO-bound, not CPU-bound. Threading should be enough, no need to spawn additional processes.

Comment: @defnull: threads are harder to kill without cooperation from them, they don't release resources properly.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I am not sure if I understood what you are trying to accomplish but if I were in your place I would try to use the [python-daemon package](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-daemon/)

I think that both `bottle` and `TFTP` could be daemonized.
As you are only in search for a simple test I guess that the examples given in the python-daemon webpage would be enough.

If you really like the idea of going daemonizing things, I would suggest also that you search about the proper daemonizing approach for your platform as this way you have several facilities to manage your daemon by making them more alike to the ones found in your OS.

For some simple examples:
http://troydhanson.wordpress.com/2012/08/21/minimal-sysvinit-launchd-and-upstart/

Comment: Pardon me if I was unclear. I will daemonize indeed. But not those 2 processes. I'm writing my own tool that will embed both bottle and TFTP and _that_ tool I will indeed daemonize with `python-daemon`. I was merely looking for a solution to run those two as separate threads/subprocesses inside my own daemon.

Comment: Should I simply delete this answer as it doesn't add anything to the problem?

Comment: Feel free to leave it :) It probably adds a bit more info on daemonizing in python in general.