# Globale Variables with Bottlpy (in background)

Tags: python, bottle

i need to use global variables in my program with either flask or bottle running as a webservice. so far im using bottle as a thread with a snippet i found here: [Starting python bottle in a thread/Process and another daemon next to it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13021762/starting-python-bottle-in-a-thread-process-and-another-daemon-next-to-it)

i basically want to go to localhost:8080/hello to increase the global variable test by one:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from bottle import route, run
from multiprocessing import Process

@route('/hello')
def hello():
    global test
    test = test + 1
    return test

def main():
    global test
    test = 0

    t = Process(target=bottle.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8080))
    t.daemon = True
    t.start()

    while(True)
        print test
        time.sleep(0.5)     

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

if i go to localhost:8080/hello with my browser i get:
    Error 500: Internal Server Error - Unhandled Exception

i cant see the exception tho, even with

```
try
    global test
    test = test + 1
    return test
except Exception e
    print e
```

Comment: How are you starting your program?  You should see the error (traceback) on stderr.

Comment: The code you posted will not run, it has syntax errors. Are you sure you posted the same code you're actually running?  E.g. the line `while(True)` is a syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

You're returning an `int` from `hello`, but you need to return an iterable (of strings).

Tip: add `debug=True` to your call to `run` to get better error info in your response.

`t = Process(target=run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8080, debug=True))`